# Using blog posts as thumbnail gallery

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to developing themes for Wordpress, but have a decent understanding of css, php and html coding.

I want my homepage to just be a responsive thumbnail grid. Each thumbnail linking to a page with a bunch of related photos with a description at the bottom with social-media abilities underneath, etc. Very similar to how a regular blog post would work linking to a single page to read the whole article.

I DON'T want to use a plugin. I figured I could manipulate code for the native gallery or something similar to achieve this. But I cannot find any resources that don't involve plugins.

Is there any decent resources for this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the_post_thumbnail(); therefore you have to enable featured image for each post in your functions.php with add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

After that you can loop through your posts and use sth. like that in your loop to get the thumbnails and links to the posts:
(I have seen no code so I have to guess, but this should get you started I think)

```
<article id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(313, 209) ); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

Comment: that seems to work great, thank you. It's a great start. Is there any resources where I can learn how to add more images on the single page. I was going to go through the code of a theme and do it that way but none come close to what I want, and most have way to much info

Comment: for example the code works, but i want to be able to use dashboard to import 'featured image' but I'm not sure where the code goes to enable a post to upload a featured image

Comment: So u want to add more images to your single-page aka your blog post? Than you just have to add images in the post editor (rte) if u then click on the featuered image on homepage u get to the post and see all the images.

Comment: Basically, most themes have a 'portfolio' page amongst the theme. I just want to make that my home page. a grid of thumbnails (that are blog posts) that link to single pages with more related and (large size) images stacked, with a description underneath.

Comment: my code in the functions.php

if (function_exists ('add_image_size')) {
 add_image_size('featured', 400, 250, true);
 add_image_size('post-thumb', 200, 125, true);
}

Comment: I haven't used 'portfolio' templates or so, but you'll have to change the post_thumbnail sizes to your thumbnail sizes and then you'll have to get the title or the_excerpt for the description